# How to find the Y Position or Vertical Position after printing data in MigraDoc and PDFSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have to generate a PDF Document. I am using both PDFSharp and MigraDoc.

While using this, the line break automatically taken care using MigraDoc. But the problem with that is the data which is being printed is dynamic. So I couldn't get the exact line count after printing a line.

NOTE:: I am not using a rectangle to print the content, I am using different technique (ahw, an inefficient method) to calculate the line height.

I am considering there would be 80 words per line but since PDFSharp uses vector graphics, the method is not stable. Some times I am getting correct but not always.

I need a way to figure out the Current Y Position or vertical position after printing a content so that i can point out the Y position to print the remaining content.

I have been google and researching for long but no positive results. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks..

Comment: is it only text that ends up in the pdf or do you have also tables and images?

Comment: @MongZhu - I don't have any images or tables..  But i have lots of content.. More than 30 pages for sure and data is totally dynamic...

Comment: it would be good if you could post some code of your technique how you print the data.
If you are using paragraphs, then may be it is possible to use the `Paragraph p.Format.Broders.` property to calculate the Y-coordinate.